# Undefined Variable: model

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii and learning it now.  Here i am trying to get the listing of the user from the users table of the database.

Following is my Users Controller function for view:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionView()
    {
        $model = new Users;

        $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
}
```

Following is my Users Model:

```
class Users extends CActiveRecord
{

public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return '{{users}}';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('fname, lname, email', 'required'),
        array('fname, lname', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('email', 'length', 'max'=>100),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, fname, lname, email', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'fname' => 'First Name',
        'lname' => 'Last Name',
        'email' => 'Email',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('fname',$this->fname,true);
    $criteria->compare('lname',$this->lname,true);
    $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
}
```

Following is my View:

```
<h1>Users</h1>

<p>
Below is the list of users, here you may add user.
</p>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'fname',
    'lname',
    'email',
),
)); ?>

<div class="view">

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?     >
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('fname')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->fname); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('lname')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->lname); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('email')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->email); ?>
<br />

</div>
```

I am getting a PHP notice saying that undefined variable: model, please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to show all users? Then you should use something like `zii.widgets.CListView`. Btw, the view is for `actionIndex` or `actionView`?

Comment: thanks for you answer, the view is for actionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were pasting _view.php.
Make sure you hand your `$model` variable from `view.php` to `_view.php`, since in `actionView()` you are only handing it to 'view'.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but like can you be more specific that what should i do

Comment: Make sure you hand your $model variable from view.php to _view.php. Look at the `renderPartial()` call in view.php :)

Answer (score 0):

field($model, 'VideoTitle')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'required' => true]) ?>
field($model, 'Description')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'required' => true]) ?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).